# How to access value from multidimensional four levels array in Twig template?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, twig

How to display value from multidimensional array in twig ?

My array is like this (it is because i can sort it easy using the keys):

```
mergedresult = Array( [key01] =>
                        Array ( [key11] => 
                                 Array ( [50] => Array( [id] => 50 [title] => title50 ) ) )              
                      [key02] =>
                        Array ( [key12] => 
                               Array ( [50] => Array( [id] => 50 [title] => title50 ) ) )
);
```

I want to access title in twig:

```
{% if mergedresult is not empty %}
<br> mergedresult is not empty <br>
 {% for evarr in mergedresult.all %} {# key=all/AND/OR evarr=array('12'=>array('id'=>12, 'title'=> ...)) #}
      {# <br> for evarr in mergedresult.all <br> #}
    {% if evarr is not empty %} 
         {# <br> if evarr is not empty  <br> #}
        {% for eventarr in evarr %} {# key=12,13,50.. eventarr=array('id'=>12, 'title'=> ...) #}
             {# <br> for eventarr in evarr <br> #}
            {% for event in eventarr %}
                {#  <br> for event in eventarr <br> #}
                <tr> {{ event.title }} </tr>
            {% endfor %} {#  <br> for event in eventarr <br> #}
        {% endfor %} {# <br> for eventarr in evarr <br> #}
    {% endif %}  {#  {% if evarr is not empty %}  #}
  {% endfor %} {# <br> for evarr in mergedresult.all <br> #}
{% endif %}
```

But nothing is displayed. If i check using commented out statements, i am getting the following result:

```
mergedresult is not empty
for evarr in mergedresult.all
if evarr is not empty
for eventarr in evarr
for eventarr in evarr
for evarr in mergedresult.all 
for eventarr in evarr
for eventarr in evarr
```

Seems twig is not able to access title, which is value nested in 4th level of multidimensional array. Is this possible? How ?

Comment: can you export your array using json_encode? will try to give you your answer using http://twigfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

I could not find in the documentation what is the limit for hash (twig data type corresponding to php array) https://mijingo.com/blog/key-value-arrays-in-twig, but in my case, i could not access title, because i used too many for loops, because my array is three-dimensional (i also have four-dimensional array 'columnresult' and was trying to access title from it using three-dimensional array name 'mergedresult' ). The correct code access title from 3rd level of multidimensional array:

```
{% if mergedresult is not empty %}
    {% for event in mergedresult.all %} {# key=12/50/... evant=array('12'=>array('id'=>12, 'title'=> ...), ..) #}
        <tr> {{ event.title }} </tr>
    {% endfor %} {#  <br> for event in eventarr <br> #}
{% endif %}
```